# Dataweave code not working mule 4 which was working in mule3

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, payload, dataweave

The following code snippet was working in 3.8 but not working in 4.1:

```
output application/java
var csv = payload
---
(csv map $ reduce ((val,acc) -> ((acc) ++ ((val)) ))) map ($ replace ',' with '\t')

input payload: 

{"D01":{"AK":"D,01,AK,0,0,0,0,0,-2.89,0.00,0,0,0,0,0",
        "AL":"D,01,AL,829.23,18506.35,0,0.00,0,-6610.91,0.00,0,0,0,159.66,-1.94"},
"D02.1":{"AK":"D,02.1,AK,0,0,0,0,0,-6.76,0.00,0,0,0,0,0",
        "AL":"D,02.1,AL,7733.77,304148.90,0,0.00,0,-42791.15,0.00,0,0,0,1347.09,-8.88"}
}
```

enter code here

Expected Output: 
    [
    "D\t01\tAK\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t-2.89\t0.00\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0",
    "D\t01\tAL\t829.23\t18506.35\t0\t0.00\t0\t-6610.91\t0.00\t0\t0\t0\t159.66\t-1.94",
    "D\t02.1\tAK\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t-6.76\t0.00\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0",
    "D\t02.1\tAL\t7733.77\t304148.90\t0\t0.00\t0\t-42791.15\t0.00\t0\t0\t0\t1347.09\t-8.88"
    ]

Am getting below Error:

org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler:

---

Message               : "You called the function 'map' with these arguments:
1: String ("{\"D01\":{\"AK\":\"D,01,AK,0,0,0,0,0,-2.89,0.00,0,0,0,0,0\", \"AL\":\"D,01,A...)
2: Function (($:Any, $$:Any) -> ???)

But it expects arguments of these types:
1: Array
2: Function

13| (csv map $ reduce ((val,acc) -> ((acc) ++ ((val)) ))) map ($ replace ',' with '\t')
     ^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Can you paste the payload content. Also can you tell us how is failing. And the expected output

Comment: I have added input payload and output result also now.

Comment: why is it not working? You need to provide either 1) what the output of this transformation was or 2) the error message you're getting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Added error which i am getting now

Comment: Thank you. Seems like the problem is your CSV is being represented as a String instead of an Array. Is it possible that your Mule 3 code had some metadata set that is not being applied to your Mule 4 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem there is, `map` in DataWeave 2 does not work on `Object` (See [changes](https://javastreets.com/blog/2017/8/mule4_dataweave2_syntax_changes_with_examples.html#_2_1_1_automatic_coercion_from_object_to_array)). DataWeave 1 allowed that and hence your code was valid for DataWeave 1.

Based on the output with DataWeave 1, I think you can use following code for DataWeave 2 -

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var csv = payload
---
flatten ((csv pluck $) map ($ pluck $)) map ($ replace ',' with '\t')
```

`pluck` will split an object into two arrays - values ($) and keys ($$).

Comment: Above code is working as expected. Appreciate your help @Manik